# MongoDB $in with an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I need to do a Mongo $in search, but I need to search items of an array.

**My search at the moment**

```
$db         = $m->data;
$collection = $db->pax;


    $searchTwo = array(
      'bookings.transactions.tranType' => array(
        '$in' => $ruleContents['tran_type']
        ),
      'agencyID' => $user->agencyID
    );

    $matchWithPax = $collection->find($searchTwo);
```

**Contents of `$ruleContents['tran_type']`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Air
    [1] => Conference
    [2] => Fee
    [3] => Rail
    [4] => Other
    [5] => Car
    [6] => Hotel
)
```

This isn't returning anything, I suspect it's to do with it being an array.

I expect to search through the $ruleContents['tran_type'] And if it matches, then do something

Comment: Can you show us the document schema by including some sample documents and what your expected output is from the above criteria?

Comment: I don't know this language/API, but I think you are using [`$in` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/) correctly. If your query does not return any result, try one criteria at a time to precisely locate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all of the $ruleContents['tran_type'] array contents to be searched in mongo $in search, you can try implode & construct the clause:

```
 '$in' => '\'["' . implode('","', $ruleContents['tran_type']) . '"]\''
```

would result:

> '$in' => '["Air","Conference","Fee","Rail","Other","Car","Hotel"]'